# OpenLayers Modify interaction in freehand mode

Tags: openlayers, ol-ext

Is there any way to enable "freehand" mode with the Modify interaction?  I am looking to edit the side of a simple polygon in freehand style.  Is there any way to do this in OpenLayers or with an extension?

```
const modify = new Modify({
    source: source,
    freehandCondition: ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly
});
map.addInteraction(modify);

let draw;

function addInteractions() {
  draw = new Draw({
    source: source,
    type: 'Polygon',
    freehandCondition: ol.events.condition.altKeyOnly
  });
  map.addInteraction(draw);
}
```

The desired process would go like this:

1. Select a segment in a polygon
2. Start freehand draw in one of the segment vertices
3. Freehand draw the segment and finish it in the other segment vertice
4. Replace initial polygon segment with the new drawn segment

Comment: How exactly you imagine freehand modify would work? How would you modify simple line with given start and end point in freehand mode?

Comment: If you had a square, click on the middle of the right side and drag inward (how Modify normally works).  Then when you hold the Shift key, it would add new vertices on mousemove.  The result would be a square with a smooth-ish concave portion on the right side.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it. Picture tells a thousand words.

Comment: My hope is a faster way to modify the side of a polygon like this by using a freehand mode: https://media.giphy.com/media/jICzIz3PivestBAGdw/giphy.gif

Comment: There is no such free hand polygon modify interaction possible in OL or el-ext, but it can be done with some coding.